# How to get hierarchy roles from DB

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring MVC project configured with the security.xml file, in there I have the roles with something like this:

```
<beans:bean id="roleHierarchy"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl">
    <beans:property name="hierarchy">
        <beans:value>
            ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_PRIVILEGED
            ROLE_PRIVILEGED > ROLE_USER
            ROLE_USER > ROLE_ANONYMOUS
        </beans:value>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

and it works great, but now I want that hierarchy to come from a table in my DataBase (I'm using MYSQL)

can you point my in the right direction? I want to keep all the security in the xml file and just be able to bring the roles from the DataBase since the roles are dynamically created with a graphic interface and stored in the DB

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need custom UserDetailsService (see [here an example](http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-security/custom-userdetailsservice-example-for-spring-3-security/))

Your user details service loads roles from DB and stores them as list of GrantedAuthority for the logged in user.

e.g.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException
{
    System.out.println("Getting access details from employee dao !!");

    // Ideally it should be fetched from database and populated instance of
    // #org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User should be returned from this method
    UserDetails user = new User(username, "password", true, true, true, true, new GrantedAuthority[]{ new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER") });
    return user;
}
```

In the example you need to add your logic to retrieve user and add roles.